# How to replace ? value in oracle sql if used the same in multiple times in same oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

Example:

```
select * from employee, department 
where 
employee.empid=?
and department.empid=?
```

--? used to get the same value for employee.empid and department.empid.

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: do you mean substitution variables &prm1 and &prm2 respectively for question marks ..? Your question is unclear, please elaborate more.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I am using this in BIRT reporting tool so i have to use ?

Comment: In your case it's sufficient to write `and department.empid = employee.empid`. In other cases, e.g. when you bind parameters from a different programming language, you just pass the same value twice, or use named parameters if they are supported.

Comment: @9000 is there a way to use something like select ? as qm from dual and use this once while query processing

Comment: @user3686372: please explain the wider scope of your task. What language / environment / tool are you using? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @9000 Oracle sql in BIRT reporting tool and java... I have a query where multiple times the substitution to be used one in inner query and another in other query so i need to declare only one parameter in BIRT query composition rather than two times...otherwise user has to provide the same value twice.

Comment: @9000 did you get my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `WITH` clause to select your parameters, so you can access them all over your query, be it in your main query or in some sub-sub-sub query:

```
with params as
(
  select
    :emp_id as emp_id,
    :dept_id as dept_id
  from dual
)
select ...
from . ..
where x.emp_id = (select emp_id from params)
  and y.emp_id <> (select emp_id from params)
  and z.dept_id = (select dept_id from params);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, your query seems to be *wrong* and your question doesn't make much sense either. In my opinion, you should **join** those tables and use **one parameter**. For example, something like this:

```
select *
from employee e join department d on e.deptno = d.deptno
where d.deptno = :par_deptno
```

You'd want to have `EMPID` as a parameter; why? What is `EMPID` doing in the `DEPARTMENT` table? It just doesn't belong there. So, either example you posted is wrong, or you don't quite understand what you're doing, or ... something else.

**[EDIT, after your comment]**

Doesn't make much sense, but - here's how you might do that (if I understood what you're saying):

```
SQL> select e.deptno e_dept,
  2         d.deptno d_dept,
  3         d.dname,
  4         e.ename
  5  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  6  join (select 10 params from dual) p on e.deptno = p.params
  7                                     and d.deptno = p.params;

    E_DEPT     D_DEPT DNAME          ENAME
---------- ---------- -------------- ----------
        10         10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10         10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10         10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: that's true...but i have another query where i am using the same parameter multiple times...so given a example.

Comment: As I said: if you join (all those) tables, you don't have to use the same parameter multiple times but only once.

Comment: that's an example. select * from employee,dept where empid = ? and dept_id in (select deptid from dept where empid=?) here is another example for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems that we don't understand each other. What is EMPID (**employee ID**) doing in the DEPT table? Examples you post are simply *wrong*, and I don't know what suggestion you expect for something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: `select * from emp,dept, (select ? as params from dual) p
where emp.empname = p.params
and dept.empname= p.params
and p.params = 'USER' `; is there a way i can use like this. so that i can give only once the parameter value.

Comment: I edited my message and posted another example; have  a look, please.